# Robust detection of texture capabilities in threejs

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I have to load some big textures in a threejs application, using the best the hardware can do.
I use:

```
var local_size = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE);
```

To determine what's the maximum size accepted by the device.
On a PC, what's returned by this call matches reality, eg if this call returns 8096 then I can use textures of this size.
On mobile devices though the situation varies quite a lot. For example, on a nexus 5, I get 4096 and a texture of this size does work.
On a Samsung Galaxy tab 3, I get 4096 but if I use this size, I just get a black texture... The maximum size I can use is 2048.
On a Nexus 4, same issue.

In summary : some browsers (at least chrome on Android) just return wrong values regarding the webgl implementation capabilities.

I found, in the Khronos webgl regression test suite, some hints on how to test the actual capabilities.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/limits/gl-max-texture-dimensions.html

However this is a lot of code and may slow down the startup of my application, so (at last) here's my question :
any ideas on how to test the actual texture capabilities of a specific device? Maybe an error condition to test if the texture creation went wrong in Threejs?

Thank you for your help!